# Fibonacci Modified Hackerrank

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm stuck with this problem on Hackerrank, regarding the dynamic programming in the Algorithms section .

> A series is defined in the following manner:
>
> Given the nth and (n+1)th terms, the (n+2)th can be computed by the
>   following relation  **T(n+2) = (Tn+1)^2 + T(n)**
>
> So, if the first two terms of the series are 0 and 1:  the **third** term
>   = 1^2 + 0 = 1  **fourth** term = 1^2 + 1 = 2  **fifth** term = 2^2 + 1 = 5  ... And so on.
>
> Given three integers A, B and N, such that the first two terms of the
>   series (1st and 2nd terms) are A and B respectively, compute the Nth
>   term of the series.
>
> Input Format
>
> You are given three space separated integers A, B and N on one line.
>
> Input Constraints  0 <= A,B <= 2  3 <= N <= 20
>
> Output Format
>
> One integer.  This integer is the Nth term of the given series when
>   the first two terms are A and B respectively.
>
> **Note**
>
> Some output may even exceed the range of 64 bit integer.

My code is the following:

```
int main() {
    int A,B,N;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &A, &B, &N);
    if (N == 1) {printf("%d\n", A); return 0;}
    if (N == 2) {printf("%d\n", B); return 0;}
    unsigned long long int C[3];
    C[0] = A; C[1] = B; C[2] = (B*B)+A;
    while((N-3)>0){
       C[0] = C[1];
       C[1] = C[2];
       C[2] = (C[1]*C[1])+C[0];
       N--;
    }
    printf("%llu\n", C[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I submit it it passes only 2/10 of the testcases (the first one and the last one if this could help).

Since I tried with a custom input to see if it works and apparently it works ( *0 1 5 gives 5*) I'm starting to think that the problem is, as the note says, that the output could be too big.

HERE IS THE [LINK](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified) TO THE PROBLEM

How can I make this big numbers fit into the array?

Comment: Using `unsigned` would give a bit more headroom.

Comment: And the question says "given  3 integers" so why are you inputting to `short`?

Comment: Look at the last line of the problem statement carefully. *"Some output may even exceed the range of 64 bit integer."*

Comment: @WeatherVane because it says the value of those 3 integers is <= 20

Comment: Even so, I don't even understand why you would use `short` except where memory is severely restricted.

Comment: @WeatherVane the memory I can use is restricted. Btw this is something I added after because I though it could solve the problem. But it doesn't.

Comment: You were "short" of 6 bytes?

Comment: Your edit: you need to make, or find a library of bignum, because the result of `0, 1, 20` is ***out of the range of 64 bit unsigned integers.***

Comment: @WeatherVane now that I've added unsigned before long long it when I try the input 0 1 20 it gives me 15863312013600091583 and I think it's correct.

Comment: No, it is incorrect. The function goes out of range on the 10th iteration.

Comment: If you moved the `printf` up into the loop (for testing), you would have seen this.

Comment: I always thought that `^` means `exclusive OR` not `multiply`

Comment: `I always thought that ^ means exclusive OR not multiply` so who coded `C[2] = (C[1]*C[1])+C[0];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is overflow. Don't be fooled by the small values of A, B, and N. The numbers `T(n)` grow quickly.

Whenever I encounter a competitive programming task that requires big integers I use a programming language with builtin support for big integers. So one way to solve this problem would be to use Python for example.

A second option is that you could implement routines to add and multiply big integers (for a given representation of big integer). These are not hard to implement.

Here is my Python implementation.

```
A, B, N = (int(x) for x in raw_input().split())
if N == 1: print(A)
elif N == 2: print(B)
else:
    for i in range(2, N):
        F = A + B*B
        A = B
        B = F
    print(F)
```

I'll let you discover the output when you execute the above code with values `A=2`, `B=2`, and `N=20`.

Comment: I know T(n) has an exponential growth and on that site I could use Java and the class BigInteger , but the challenge to me is to solve the problem with C.

Comment: Then implement functions to add/multiply big integers, which you could implement as character arrays for example. Then post your code if you still need help :).

Comment: I tried your code on Hackerrank and it passed all the testcases. Turns out the 0 1 20 is WAY bigger than the C program calculated.

Answer (score -1):

You must use BigInteger data type for this problem. Otherwise there may be overflow.Java has BigInteger data type.
Here is my java implementation.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String argc[]) {
        BigInteger bi1,bi2,bi3 = null;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t1 = in.nextInt();
        int t2 = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        bi1 = BigInteger.valueOf(t1);
        bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(t2);
         for (int i=0;i<n-2;i++){
           bi3 = bi1.add(bi2.pow(2));
           bi1 = bi2;
           bi2 = bi3;
         }
    System.out.println(bi3);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try with Java and the BigInteger Class or with Python